# App is not loading and getting XPC connection was invalidated error in iPhone OS 14.2

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiwindow, xcode12

I am trying to run my App on my iPhone 6S OS Version 14.2 using my Xcode Version 12.2

The problem is while installing the App, the App got stuck in Launch screen, seems like getting blank screen and getting below error:

> [xpc] XPC connection was invalidated

I am just getting this connection invalidated in console without getting any error. My breakpoints are going to the next screen but the UI is stuck. Tried installing the same App on OS 13.3 is working fine. After updating the Xcode and iPhone version from 13 to 14 I started getting the issue.

**AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        FirebaseConfiguration().setLoggerLevel(FirebaseLoggerLevel.min)
        
        self.foxManager = FoxManager.createInstance()
        
        // Configure Firebase
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        // Remove notification badges
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
            
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                        
            let loginVC = AppManager.UserStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginvc") as? LoginVC
            
            let navigationController = NavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC)
            //navigationController.setViewControllers([navVCrootVC], animated: false)
            
            //Disable left swipe from any screen
            navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
            navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false

            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
            
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        
        return true
    }
```